# Помогите разделить header и sidebar с контентом

Tags: html, css

Пытался разделить header, sidebar и main(контент). Никак не получилось. Прошу помощи)

```css
/* Google Font Import - Poppins */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

 :root {
  /* ===== Colors ===== */
  --body-color: #E4E9F7;
  --sidebar-color: #FFF;
  --primary-color: #695CFE;
  --primary-color-light: #F6F5FF;
  --toggle-color: #DDD;
  --text-color: #707070;
  /* ====== Transition ====== */
  --tran-03: all 0.2s ease;
  --tran-03: all 0.3s ease;
  --tran-04: all 0.3s ease;
  --tran-05: all 0.3s ease;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  transition: var(--tran-05);
}

 ::selection {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
}

body.dark {
  --body-color: #18191a;
  --sidebar-color: #242526;
  --primary-color: #3a3b3c;
  --primary-color-light: #3a3b3c;
  --toggle-color: #fff;
  --text-color: #ccc;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background: var(--sidebar-color);
  transition: var(--tran-05);
  z-index: 10;
}


/* ===== Sidebar ===== */

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  background: var(--sidebar-color);
  transition: var(--tran-05);
  z-index: 100;
}

.sidebar.close {
  width: 88px;
}


/* ===== Reusable code - Here ===== */

.sidebar li {
  height: 45px;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-header .image,
.sidebar .icon {
  min-width: 60px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.sidebar .icon {
  min-width: 60px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sidebar .text,
.sidebar .icon {
  color: var(--text-color);
  transition: var(--tran-03);
}

.sidebar .text {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar.close .text {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* =========================== */

.sidebar .sidebar-header {
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-header .image-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-header .logo-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sidebar-header .image-text .name {
  margin-top: 2px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.sidebar-header .image-text .profession {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  display: block;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-header .image {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-header .image img {
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-header .toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -25px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: var(--sidebar-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: var(--tran-05);
}

body.dark .sidebar .sidebar-header .toggle {
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.sidebar.close .toggle {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
}

.sidebar .menu {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.sidebar li a {
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: var(--tran-03);
}

.sidebar li a:hover {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

.sidebar li a:hover .icon,
.sidebar li a:hover .text {
  color: var(--sidebar-color);
}

body.dark .sidebar li a:hover .icon,
body.dark .sidebar li a:hover .text {
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.sidebar .menu-bar {
  height: calc(100% - 55px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.menu-bar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar .menu-bar .mode {
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: var(--primary-color-light);
  position: relative;
  transition: var(--tran-05);
}

.menu-bar .mode .sun-moon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 60px;
}

.mode .sun-moon i {
  position: absolute;
}

.mode .sun-moon i.sun {
  opacity: 0;
}

body.dark .mode .sun-moon i.sun {
  opacity: 1;
}

body.dark .mode .sun-moon i.moon {
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu-bar .bottom-content .toggle-switch {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle-switch .switch {
  position: relative;
  height: 22px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: var(--toggle-color);
  transition: var(--tran-05);
}

.switch::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: var(--sidebar-color);
  transition: var(--tran-04);
}

body.dark .switch::before {
  left: 20px;
}

.home {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  transition: var(--tran-05);
}

.home .text {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--text-color);
  padding: 12px 60px;
}

.sidebar.close~.home {
  left: 78px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: calc(100% - 78px);
}

body.dark .home .text {
  color: var(--text-color);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>@yield('page-title', config('app.name'))</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('css/app.css') }}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">--}}
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>
  <header>

  </header>
  <nav class="sidebar close">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <div class="image-text">
        <span class="image">
                        <!--<img src="logo.png" alt="">-->
                    </span>

        <div class="text logo-text">
          <span class="name">Test</span>
          <span class="profession">Site Test</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <i class='bx bx-chevron-right toggle'></i>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-bar">
      <div class="menu">
        <li class="nav-link">
          <a href="#">
            <i class='bx bx-home-alt icon'></i>
            <span class="text nav-text">Главная</span>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-link">
          <a href="#">
            <i class='bx bx-bar-chart-alt-2 icon'></i>
            <span class="text nav-text">Тест</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </div>

      <div class="bottom-content">
        <li class="">
          <a href="#">
            <i class='bx bx-log-out icon'></i>
            <span class="text nav-text">Logout</span>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="mode">
          <div class="sun-moon">
            <i class='bx bx-moon icon moon'></i>
            <i class='bx bx-sun icon sun'></i>
          </div>
          <span class="mode-text text">Dark mode</span>

          <div class="toggle-switch">
            <span class="switch"></span>
          </div>
        </li>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <div>
      CONTENT
    </div>
  </main>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!--
    <script src="{{ url('js/script.js') }}"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А где Ваш открывающийся тег `<body>` ?

Comment: Под <script></script>

Comment: Это закрывающий тег, а я спросил где Вы его открыли?

Comment: Исправил пост. Добавил в код